# How to get module AutoMenu working

Tags: 6

I try to use the module automenu 6.x-2.x-dev in drupal 6.30. I have installed the module in /sites/all/modules and then activated the module.
Further I added some content (story,page) leave the menu link title empty, choose a parent menu item and published the newly created content; but I never gets a menu item created.

I created the content as admin, so there shouldn't be a permission issue.

Could anyone explain me how this module works? I googled a lot, but find any helpful information.

Comment: Welcome on Drupal Answers! Did you read the module documentation?

Comment: yes I did. but perhaps my english isn't good enough too really understand the explanations. in the meantime I found some information that lead me further.